# how to design view layout in vertical on android

Tags: android

hi all
i need to design view layout between two linear layout. i see view's property for orientation. **i want to put view layout by vertically between linear layout2 and linear layout3.** please assist me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: at what? where's your code? or a mockup of your desired layout? you should help us by providing some more information, so we could help you. thanks!

Comment: i paste my code by edit question.please check my question

Comment: thanks (and sorry, it wasn't formatted, so I couldn't see it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNEW" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textViewNEW"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now You have three LinearLayout with horizontal orientation one under another... Is this what you wanted to achieve?

And it is even not recommended to use LinearLayout when only one control is within it...
So next example should be better:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNEW" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textViewNEW1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textViewNEW2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, now it should reflect it... I deleted the LinearLayout1 and made the main LinearLayout to be LinearLayout1 with its vertical orientation...

Comment: thanks its usefull. is there any way to draw a line vertically